# when will an activity instance reclaimed in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

After calling onDestroy() of an Activity,when will the activity instance reclaimed?
When reference count of the Activity instance is zero,
or when system need some memory,or when else?

Comment: What about garbage collector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onDestroy()` will just release all the resources it holds.

As per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

> An activity will do all setup of "global" state in onCreate(), and release all remaining resources in onDestroy(). For example, if it has a thread running in the background to download data from the network, it may create that thread in onCreate() and then stop the thread in onDestroy().

Activity will be GCed only when the Dalvik decides that it needs to be GCed. Also for the Activity to be GCed all it's live reference should be removed.

Android OS will simply kill the process if App with higher priority is to be run and no memory is available.

Answer (score 1):

> when will the activity instance reclaimed?

It will be garabage-collected sometime after there are no more references to it and the garbage collector gets around to collecting that bit of garbage. Bear in mind that the Dalvik VM garabage collector does not try to collect all garbage on each GC pass, to try to minimize CPU impact.